# Как поймать callback_data при нажатии inline кнопки в группе tg

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота в телеге для приёма заказов. Когда пользователь совершает заказ, отправляется сообщение в группу tg, где админ может принять заказ или отказать. Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бота в админы группы добавил, разрешил добавляться в чаты, разрешил inline мод.
В основном коде написал две функции для inline кнопок:

```
async def confirmed_order(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
   await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, text="Заказ принят, перезвоните клиенту!", show_alert=True)
async def canceled_order(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
   await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, text="В заказе отказано, перезвоните клиенту!", show_alert=True)
```

А также хэндлеры

```
dp.register_callback_query_handler(confirmed_order, lambda c: c.data == 'confirmed', state=Order.final)
dp.register_callback_query_handler(canceled_order, lambda c: c.data == 'canceled', state=Order.final)
```

Но по какой-то неведомой мне причине хэндлеры не обрабатываются. Что нужно сделать, чтобы бот хэндлил запросы из группы?

Comment: Посмотрите на state, возможно это значение не правильно выставляется во время вызова через Inline Mode